# Call to pop failing in my java code

Tags: java

```
public void CardToPile() {
    waste.push(reserve.pop);
}
```

Comment: What should it be doing?

Comment: In the future, please post the error instead of saying "it doesn't work". The error contains information about the cause of the problem. You know, once the cause is *understood*, a solution is *obvious* :)

Comment: Am really sorry, ill be more careful in the future :s

Comment: BTW: in Java, method names ought to start with lowercase. http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public void CardToPile() {
        waste.push(reserve.pop()); //Here is the error
    }
```

You need to add the parens in order to call the method.

Comment: Oh would that Java could be more like Perl. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If by "not working" you mean that it does not compile, it might be because your call to  `reserve.pop`  seems incorrect. You might have meant `reserve.pop()`.